# What Variance equation is this textbook using?

Tags: variance, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution, negative-binomial, mixing

I'm doing a question on a Gamma/Poisson mix, which turns into a negative binomial. What I don't understand is the answer to the question - most of the answer makes sense to me (normal approximation and so forth), but the author seems to be using variance as:

$$V[Total] = (E[Count] * (E[X^2]-E[X]^2)) + E[X]^2*V[Count])$$

How did the author arrive at such a conclusion? I'm very confused.

[image: Background]

[image: Question]

[image: Answer - with variance]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T = \sum^C_{i=1} X_i$ where $C$ and $X_i$ are independent, by the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_variance),

\begin{align}
Var(T) &= E(Var(T|C)) + Var(E(T|C)) 
\\&= E(CVar(X_i)) + Var(CE[X])\\
&=E(C) Var(X) + E[X]^2 Var(C)
\end{align}